# Laravel bug: making column nullable stops it from being added to table

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, laravel-9

I have a SQLite database with the following migration defined:

```
    Schema::create("views", function(Blueprint $table){

        $table->integer("match_id");
        $table->string("pov");
        $table->string("teams");     
        $table->text("moves");

        $table->bigIncrements("id");    
        $table->date("created_at");
        $table->date("updated_at"); 
    });
```

Note: `id` is the primary key of the table, `match_id` should just be treated as any other column.

This all works just fine, but I want `match_id` to be nullable. I tried changing the `$table -> integer("match_id")` to the following:

```
$table->integer("match_id")->nullable()->change();
//Also tried $table->integer("match_id")->nullable(true)->change();
```

I also ran 'composer require doctrine/dbal', which I saw online

When I try running php artisan migrate, it says there is nothing to migrate. And when I run php artisan migrate:fresh, for some reason the match_id column just doesn't get added to the database at all, even though every other column works just fine. Any reason this might be?

Comment: Since you can run `migrate:fresh` why not directly change it to the original migration file instead of creating a new migration  file for it ?

Comment: @xenooooo sorry for the confusion: That was a change to the original migration file. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Since that was a modification to the _original_ migration you don't need the `->change()` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `migrate:fresh` is an option (as pointed by @xenooooo), just edit your original migration to:

```
Schema::create("views", function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements("id");
    $table->integer("match_id")->nullable();
    $table->string("pov");
    $table->string("teams");     
    $table->text("moves");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This should fix the problem. With `migrate:fresh` you don't need a second migration just to change, since it will drop all tables and create everything again. Also I've changed the order of the primary key (just in case of this be the problem of `migrate:fresh` not creating the `match_id` column), and changed the timestamps format. In Laravel you don't need to create manually the timestamps, `"$table->timestamps()"` do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

By using this

> $table->foreignId('match_id')->nullable(); 
> $table->integer('match_id')->nullable();

In Laravel 7

you can make "**match_id**" (nullable & integer) or foreign-key by using this code

> $table->foreignId('test_id')->nullable(); 
> $table->integer('tint_id')->nullable();

As i used it in picture
here is code
[image]

and here is my db
[image]